# How to reload a jsp from a servlet using Post?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, file-upload, reload

Upload.jsp

```
<form id="upload" name="upload" method="post" 
     action="UploadServlet"enctype="multipart/form-data">  
     <br />  
     <div class="obrazek" id="img-4049424" 
          style="position: relative; z-index:0;">   
        <div> 
           <%=request.getAttribute("mensaje")%> <img src="img/upload/<%=request.getAttribute("logotipo")%>" 
                  alt="" style="float: left;width: 120px; height: 120px;">   
        </div>  
        <span class="upload-wrapper">  
            <img src="img/up_16.gif" alt="" style="margin-top: 50px;"> 
            <a  href="javascript:doClick()" id="fileSelect" style="font-weight: bold;" >Cargar logotipo...</a>
        </span>
    </div> 
    <div id="uploadfile" style="position: absolute; background-color:transparent; 
                                width: 210px; height: 215px; 
                                overflow: hidden; 
                                z-index: -1; opacity: 0; 
                                top: 5px; left: 5px; 
                                background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" > 
        <input id="file"  name="file" type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" 
             style="font-size: 15px; position: absolute; width: 100%; 
                    height: 100%;" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"> 
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="Subir logotipo" />
</form>
```

UploadServlet.java

```
 mensaje="successfully";
 request.setAttribute("logotipo", fileName);
 request.setAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);
 request.getRequestDispatcher("vistas/Upload.jsp")
      .forward(request, response);
```

What I need is reload to Upload.jsp  to display the uploaded image, because now I no image appears on the jsp and the file is loaded successfully...

Comment: It looks like you're already doing it. Maybe your issue is a caching problem. Set no-cache headers on the JSP.

Comment: I added to the jsp no-cache, but still gives me the same problem that can not find the image I uploaded.

Comment: Try <img src="/img/.. or <img src="./img/... rather than <img src="img/

Comment: I tryed what you said but it did not work. The direction is fine the only thing That the image is not reloaded into the jsp and if I inspect element to the browser the address of the image is correct and the image I uploaded Appears also, but  just not the sample en la jsp